# com visible .net class works from shell but not asp

Tags: .net, asp-classic, com-interop

I'm trying to utilize a simple .NET class.  To do this I use:
1) gacutil /i myassembly.dll
2) regasm myassembly.dll

Running this in a .vbs script from the console shows me that it's working in theory.

```
dim dd
dim rs
set dd = createobject("mynamespace.myclass")
rs = dd.AllCaps("It Works!")
Wscript.Echo rs
```

returns "IT WORKS!"

Doing the exact operation in classic asp

```
dim dd
dim rs
set dd = server.createobject("mynamespace.myclass")
rs = dd.AllCaps("It Works!")
response.write rs
```

returns "error '80131509'

/myfolder/mywebpage.asp, line 9 "

What is missing that is preventing me from running it through a classic ASP page?

Comment: Is it possible the bitness doesn't match (the VBScript is executing as x64 and the Classic ASP is executing as x86)?

Comment: @vcsjones Thanks, but that wasn't it.

Answer (score 2):

After following the directions on [Error message when you browse a web server that has Internet Explorer installed: "ASP 0177:8000ffff"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945701) and then restarting my server it worked.

Following the above directions I found that I was missing an entry in my registery **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_IGNORE_ZONES_INITIALIZATION_FAILURE_KB945701** so I followed the directions to add it.  A DWORD entry should be made for w3wp.exe with a value of 1.

But then again, maybe just restarting the computer did the trick.